# How to allow a user to stay logged in when not using forms authentication and using Claims with OAUTH in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0, session-state, claims-based-identity

We are currently using OAUTH and claims identites to log in our user for a MVC web application. Now, below are the current settings we are using in the web config.

```
<system.web>

<authentication mode="None" />

<compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<customErrors mode="On" />
    <identity impersonate="false" password="" userName="" />
    <sessionState useHostingIdentity="true" />      
</system.web>
```

Below is also where we handle a log in for the user account. I am trying to figure out if I add the users login to a HttpCookie, and set it for two weeks, is this done the right way and also how do i then check that every time they come back to the site and handle a log in without sending them to login screen? I am probably going about this the wrong way, but have never done it. Once i see it then it will make sense hopefully. Here is the code from the account controller.

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var loginInfo = _accountService.ValidateUser(model);

                if (loginInfo == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Login user or password");
                }
                else
                {


                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginInfo.UserId),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, loginInfo.UserId),
                        new Claim(
                            @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider",
                            "ASP.NET Identity"),
                    }, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

                    var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                    // Set current principal
                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;

                    TAM.Web.Models.ShipperSearchEntities db = new TAM.Web.Models.ShipperSearchEntities();                        
                    var ShipItemCount = new ObjectParameter("pItemCount", typeof(int));
                    var RFQItemCount = new ObjectParameter("pItemCount", typeof(int));
                    var CheckOutItemCount = new ObjectParameter("pItemCount", typeof(int));
                    var MenuString = new ObjectParameter("pMenuString", typeof(string));
                    var IsXInvoice = new ObjectParameter("pIsXInvoice", typeof(string));

                    int SIC = 0;
                    int RIC = 0;
                    int CIC = 0;
                    string menuList = "";

                    SessionHelper.SetCartName("Standard");

                    db.TAM_Get_ShipItemCount(loginInfo.UserId, ShipItemCount);
                    db.TAM_GetRFQItemCount(loginInfo.UserId, RFQItemCount);
                    db.TAM_GetCheckOutCount(loginInfo.UserId, "Default",  CheckOutItemCount);
                    db.TAM_Get_MenuAccessList(loginInfo.UserId, MenuString);
                    db.TAM_GetXInvoiceCustomer(loginInfo.CustId, IsXInvoice);

                    SIC = Convert.ToInt16(ShipItemCount.Value);
                    RIC = Convert.ToInt16(RFQItemCount.Value);
                    CIC = Convert.ToInt16(CheckOutItemCount.Value);
                    menuList = Convert.ToString(MenuString.Value);



                    SessionHelper.SetCustId(loginInfo.CustId);
                    SessionHelper.SetDefaultVendor(loginInfo.DefaultVendor);
                    SessionHelper.SetEmpId(loginInfo.EmpId);
                    SessionHelper.SetUserTitle(loginInfo.UserTitle);
                    SessionHelper.SetMmlCustId(loginInfo.MMLCustId);
                    SessionHelper.SetPartnerCode(loginInfo.PartnerCode);
                    SessionHelper.SetToItemIdentify(loginInfo.TOItemIdentify);
                    SessionHelper.SetUserId(loginInfo.UserId);
                    SessionHelper.SetUserIdEmail(loginInfo.UserIdEmail);
                    SessionHelper.SetWebSecurityCode(loginInfo.WebSecurityCode);
                    SessionHelperOther.shipperCart.SetShipItemCount(SIC);
                    SessionHelperOther.shipperCart.SetRFQItemCount(RIC);
                    SessionHelperOther.checkOutCart.SetCheckOutItemCount(CIC);
                    //SessionHelperOther.menuAccessList.SetMenuAccess(menuList);
                    //SessionHelperOther.menuAccessList.SetMenuAccess2(menuList);
                    SessionHelper.SetMenuAccess3(menuList);
                    SessionHelper.SetIsUserLevel2Access(SessionHelper.GetMenuAccess2("INVENTORYSEARCH", "ADD")); //need to modify this, but for now assuming it is a level 2 access user.
                    SessionHelper.SetCartName("Standard");

                    SessionHelper.SetXInvoice(Convert.ToString(IsXInvoice.Value));

                    //set session value for current user web access level. Not used for menus!
                    SessionHelper.SetUserWebAccessLevel(loginInfo.UserWebAccessLevel);

                    if (model.RememberMe)
                    {
                        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
                        {
                            IsPersistent = true                                
                        }, identity);

                        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("tamUsername");
                        cookie.Value = loginInfo.UserId;
                        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14);

                        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Response.Cookies.Append("tamUsername", loginInfo.UserId);                            
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
                        {      
                            IsPersistent = true,
                            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2)                                
                        }, identity);
                        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Response.Cookies.Delete("tamUsername");
                    }

                    if (null != returnUrl && returnUrl.Length > 10)
                    {
                        return Redirect("~/" + returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Home");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Username or Password");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Hopefully this is enough information, and any help is greatly appreciated. As always, thanks in advance and great community!

Comment: the user's login status is stored in user's cookie with a token. The token is handled by asp.net's built in auth framework. I don't think im seeing the code where you are sending that token back

Comment: So how can i retrieve that? The end goal is that if they marked 'Stay Logged In' that even a day later when they come to the site it will authenticate them automatically, and direct right to home screen. Not sure how i check that prior to loading the login screen.

Comment: @Steve, that is what i am wondering. We never had the lines of code where setting HttpCookie for tamUsername cookie. So i added that and was wondering if i need to retrieve that before sending them to login, and how to handle that.

Comment: @Steve, regarding the cookie being sent back. I read some more on OAUTH, and see that it handles all of this in the middle wear. So are you speaking of me needing to tie into the events callback, and get the info from there? If so, how do i handle that user coming back to the site, and logging them in?  -Thanks- (And apologies for all the questions)

Comment: if you are using the default one then you should be able to do that in a single call. Just create a default MVC website thru VS and you should be able to find the codes in there

Comment: Ah, good idea. I already have an entire site built, but i could do that to verify differences. Thanks.